# renderメソットのコードが理解できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

今ツイッターのようなWEBサイトを作っています。
他人のGithubを参照しているのですが”友達をみつける”事に機能するfriends findのindex.html.erbに理解できないコードが出てきました。

```
<%= render(@users) || "Couldn't Find Friends at the current moment" %>
```

と

```
<%= render 'partials/load_more', items: @users %>
```

の部分です。

```
 <%= render(@users) || "Couldn't Find Friends at the current moment" %>の方で、render(@users)と@usersが()でくくられているのはなぜでしょうか？これは引数という事でしょうか？また||は何を意味するのでしょうか？

 <%= render 'partials/load_more', items: @users %>の方では
```

'partials/load_more'はパーシャルメソットを呼び出しているという事でしょうか？それともこれはメッセージということなのでしょうか？

お願いいたします。
ちなみに、index.html.erbの全体は

```
<div class="tw-form row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div id="find_friends" class="well">
      <h4><b>Find Friends</b></h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          <%= render(@users) || "Couldn't Find Friends at the current moment" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="load-more">
      <%= render 'partials/load_more', items: @users %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

のようになっていて、
findfriendsのcontrollerは

```
class FindFriendsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.where("id not in (?) AND id != ?", current_user.friend_ids, current_user).paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

のようになっています。

Answer (score 1):

#### 前者について

`@users`をRailsが勝手に`_user.html.erb`の繰り返しとして展開してくれます。
`||`を続ける書き方は初めて見ましたが`@users`が0件の場合に出力されるものと思います。

下記URLを見ていただければ理解できるかと思います。
http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/updating_and_deleting_users?version=4.2#sec-partial_refactoring

#### 後者について

`app/views/partials/_load_more.html.erb`を描画(render)しています。
同時に`items`という名前の引数に`@users`を渡しているので、`_load_more.html.erb`内で`items`という変数を使うことが出来ます。